# Adding/Defining Jars in Hive permanently

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I was trying to add a jar in Hive classpath using below add command.

Command: hive> add myjar.jar

but whenever i login to hive, i need to add myjar.jar using add cmd.
Is there any way I can add it permanently in Hive Classpath.

Regards, Mohammed Niaz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this to your .hiverc file

```
  add jar myjar.jar
```

have a look at this if you require further info

http://hadooped.blogspot.in/2013/08/hive-hiverc-file.html

Comment: please add some more explanation or please add it to the comment section

Comment: doesn't this answers his quesiton ?

Answer (score 6):

In order to add them permanently recommended ways are as follows.

1. add in hive-site.xml

   `<property>
   <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
   <value>file://localpath/yourjar.jar</value>
   </property>`
2. Copy and paste the JAR file to the `${HIVE_HOME}/auxlib/` folder

   Source: Apache hive essentials book