# Parse XML and store in Hive table

Tags: xml, xpath, hive, apache-pig

I am using **XPath** to parse XML using **pig**, but in my use case i have to parse the entire xml file and move it to **hive** table. I am thinking of using XPath to parse the XML file and than move that parsed data to hive table using pig. But is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: Can you provide the sample xml file ?

Comment: @SandeepSingh actually it is confidential for my company and also having very sensitive data so i cant share it. You can think of it as 30000 lines of XML data.

Comment: I can understand it. You can parse XML file using Hive and XPath. Based on these information, I can suggests one answer. please see it below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can parse XML file in Hive using hivexmlserde.

Create an external Hive table using hivexmlserde and put all xml file on that xml location(All xml file should be similar). Using this serde you need define start and end tag in create table statement and XPath of attributes you want to fetch.

Please see the example below.

```
add jar /home/udf_jars/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_test_xml(
col1            string,
col2            string,
col3            string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.col1"="/Books/col1/text()",
"column.xpath.col2"="/Books/col2/text()",
"column.xpath.col3"="/Books/col3/text()"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION ' /user/user1/xml/data'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<Books",
"xmlinput.end"="</Books>");
```

For more detailed information, please visit [Hive-XML-Options](http://shannonholgate.com/hadoop/Hive-XML-Options/) link for more about it.

**Update: How to select Data from table.**

You need to add the `hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar` before query. Please see the example below.

```
hive> add jar /path/to/jar/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;
Added [add jar /path/to/jar/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar] to class path
Added resources: [add jar /path/to/jar/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar]
hive> use mydatabase_name;
OK
Time taken: 0.021 seconds
hive> select * from xm_table;
```

You can also set this jar permanently to avoid adding all the time before querying. Please follow below link

[Adding/Defining Jars in Hive permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444542/adding-defining-jars-in-hive-permanently)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have one question can i put all my xml files in one location in same folder
like `LOCATION ' /user/user1/xml/data/'` where **data** is my folder name ?

Comment: Yes, you can put, if all xml files are with similar structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I tried your way i am getting now error but in my table null values are there. Is there anything i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you using your query like this. hive -e 'add jar /path/to/jar/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar; use db_name; select * from tbl_name;'

Comment: i opened hive from shell and then i am writing what you mentioned in answer.

Comment: Please check update answer to know about how to select data. If it doesn't work. Please check your `Xpath`. Your `XPath` might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. But next time again when i want to parse xml i have to create the external table again or can i insert it in existing one ?

Comment: yes, you can insert xml file with same schema. but if schema is different for new xml then you need to create table again  based on that schema.

Comment: Than next time i cant use create external table command i have to use insert command. How would that command be ? is there any change i have to do in my code.

Comment: Since your table is an external table, you just need to copy other xml files in table HDFS location. Whatever file is there, will reflect to that particular table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response and explanation.

Comment: My xml files is very complex and for that parsing is getting very difficult as i cannot specify the exact path of the tag that i want to parse. How can i achieve this ? please help as i am struggling very bad in this case.